# Does Huffman Encoding produce the only optimal String?

Tags: huffman-coding

I know that Huffman coding produces an optimal solution, but are there any more solutions using the same number of bits (not including just flipping the ones and zeros or switching the encoding for letters which appear with the same frequency).

Comment: Huffman encoding produces a code, not a string. Can you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Huffman encoding can be viewed as a nondeterministic procedure for producing codes. It cannot produce every minimum redundancy code, though – every code it produces satisfies the *sibling property* (see [Gallager](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/65e6/ef044d951d2c3cbf7512b6bfa83a8b2b0739.pdf)).